# Can Same email address enter the Journey with below conditions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

We would have customer records with same email but a different customer key- Subscriber key.
Below are the conditions I use-
1)Send relationship is associated with a unique contact key as subscriber key but not email
2)Entry criteria is set as No reentry.

I assume the entry criteria would only be checked with Contactkey/subscriberkey but not the email. So here the customer with different subscriberkey but same email would enter the Journey ? Or am I wrong?

Comment: correct re-entry setting sare done at the subkey level, email address is not checked

Comment: That's right, there's (sadly) no option to deduplicate by email in Journey Builder.